# Submit several pull requests that depends on each other

Tags: git, github, branch, pull-request

I forked a project on Github. So far I have used the usual approach which consist in creating a specific branch, make some specific changes, push it to origin and create the pull request for the upstream repo.

Now let's assume I have created branch B1 to fix a problem in the code and create a pull request out of it. Then I want to keep working and add a new feature. So I create branch B2 from the same point as B1 on master.

The problem I have is that for the code in B2 to work properly I need to also get the fix from B1. How to manage that on my local repo knowing that the pull request from B1 has not yet been integrated in upstream so I cannot fetch-merge from upstream before branching B2.

Am I clear :-) ?

Comment: You are clear, and I have experienced this issue before. `git rebase` is your friend here. There are several things you could do: one is to create B2 on top of B1, work on it there, and once B1 has been merge to upstream, you rebase B2 on top of upstream. Another option is to start your branch on top of upstream, and merge B1 into it. Then, once B1 is merged into upstream, you do an interactive rebase on top of new upstream changes and drop the merge commit (`git rerere` is your friend if you go for the second approach, make sure you enable it).

Comment: Of course, if you don't mind strange-looking history with a lot of merge commits, you don't have to rebase, just merge whatever branches you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your branch B2 from your branch B1, so it will contain the fix. Then, once B1 is merged in master, you can rebase the branch B2 on master and continue to work on it.